# Override TestNG's getTestName method

Tags: interface, overriding, testng

I execute a TestNG test using a dataProvider.
So I set the testName via @BeforeMethod and I override getTestName().

This works so far, but it seems TestNG is calling the test's getTestName in the beginning
before it starts. This happens when an exception was thrown during configuration, so the @BeforeMethod is not executed and therefore my test name is null.

Is there anyway to call the original method, the one that would have been called if I would not have overwritten it :D since I implement an interface an do not extend from another class I cannot use `super.getTestName()`.

Any way to solve this may be?

```
@Test(groups = {TestGroups.READY}, description = "check help on each tab")
public class HelpTest extends TestControl implements ITest {

    // overriding to return my individual testname, but is null at the beginning
    @Override
    public String getTestName() {
        return TestControl.getCurrentTestName();
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "tabs")
    public Iterator<Object[]> tabs() {
        Set<Object[]> list = new LinkedHashSet<Object[]>();
        for (Tab tab : Tab.values()) {
            list.add(new Object[]{tab});
        }
        return list.iterator();
    }

    // before the test below starts, i set my individual testname
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setTestName(Method method, Object[] testData) {
        TestControl.setCurrentTestName(method.getName() + "_" + StringUtils.capitalize(testData[0].toString().toLowerCase()));
    }

    // executing the test with the given data provider
    @Test(dataProvider = "tabs")
    public void testHelpSites(Tab tab) throws Exception {
        TestActions.goTab(tab).callHelp(tab).checkHelp();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I figured it out, I also use a TestReporter via `AbstractWebDriverEventListener` and `ITestListener` and on its `onTestStart(ITestResult result)` it's calling the test's name and that's the source of the call before the `@BeforeMethod` call.

I solved it by checking if `result.getName()` is null, which calls the test's `getTestName()` if it implements `ITest` and if it's null I use the original name from `result.getMethod.getMethodName()`. Not pretty, but rare :D

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem using ITestNGMethod testng class.

ITestNGMethod method = result.getMethod(); // result is ITestResult Object
method.getMethodName(); // This will return method name.

```
My complete method here:
    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
    ITestNGMethod method = result.getMethod();
    String message = "Test Execution is Successful:"+method.getMethodName();
    }
```

Hope this helps